# what is the probability of putting s balls into 365 boxes with box 1 and box 2 having at least one balls in it?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am doing one probability problem about s persons and their birthdays. This question is equivalent to my title... I have no idea to calculate this probability in expressions. If s is a certain number (2 or 3 best...), I may get the answer by listing all the cases. But now totally missing.. Any hint? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**:

Let $B_{i}$ denote the number of balls in box $i$.

- $P\left(B_{1}>0\wedge B_{2}>0\right)=1-P\left(B_{1}=0\vee B_{2}=0\right)$
- $P\left(B_{1}=0\vee B_{2}=0\right)=P\left(B_{1}=0\right)+P\left(B_{2}=0\right)-P\left(B_{1}=0\wedge B_{2}=0\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $A$ is the occasion in which box 1 and box 2 have at least one ball in each, Calculate $P(A^c)$ which is either box 1 or box 2 having no balls at all.